# Find the coordinates of $M$ and $N$ where $g$ crosses the $x$-axis and $y$-axis.

Tags: coordinate-systems

> We have the line $g$ that passes through $A(-3;-4)$ and $B(6;2)$. Find
>   the coordinates of $M$ and $N$ where $g$ crosses the $x$-axis and
>   $y$-axis.

When we make a graph, we see that $M(3;0)$ and $N(0;-2)$. Is there a general formula that I can use without making a reasonable graph to see the coordinates?

Comment: Have you tried finding the equation of the line passing through $A$ and $B$? Then you can substitute $y=0$ for the $x$-axis and $x=0$ for the $y$-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of your line is $y=mx+n$. $m$ denotes the slope $$m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{2}{3}$$ and we get $n=-2$. Now we can compute the intersection points with the axis:
$$x=0,y=-2$$ and $$y=0,x=3$$

Comment: How you got that $n=-2$?

Comment: I mean if I understood $n$ is equal to $y$ when $x=0$.

Comment: Plug in the coordinates of one point, for instance $$x=6,y=2$$ and you will get $n$

Comment: I understood it. Thank you! In my case, the line is $g$. Can I write the equation  $g=\dfrac{2}{3}x-2$? Should I use $y=\dfrac{2}{3}x-2$?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova Yes, use $g(\color{blue}x)=\frac23x-2$